# Pandas DataFrame max, min and mean fails on columns with Nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to compute the max, min and mean of every column in a pandas DataFrame. I am however running into some trouble sanitizing my columns.

One of my columns contains some "?"s instead of a value I tried to clean this by doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Auto.csv")

df["horsepower"].replace("?", np.nan, inplace=True)  # sanitize the horsepower column

min_values = df.drop(columns=["name"]).dropna().min().to_dict()
max_values = df.drop(columns=["name"]).dropna().max().to_dict()
mean_values = df.drop(columns=["name"]).dropna().mean().to_dict()
```

When doing this the min, mean and max values are incorrect! Notice that I am dropping the "name" column as I want to exclude qualitative data.

The data-set can be downloaded here http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Auto.csv

EDIT:

```
Minimum values:  {'mpg': 9.0, 'cylinders': 3.0, 'displacement': 68.0, 'horsepower': 100.0, 'weight': 1613.0, 'acceleration': 8.0, 'year': 70.0, 'origin': 1.0}
Maximum values:  {'mpg': 46.6, 'cylinders': 8.0, 'displacement': 455.0, 'horsepower': 98.0, 'weight': 5140.0, 'acceleration': 24.8, 'year': 82.0, 'origin': 3.0}
Mean values:  {'mpg': 23.44591836734694, 'cylinders': 5.471938775510204, 'displacement': 194.41198979591837, 'horsepower': inf, 'weight': 2977.5841836734694, 'acceleration': 15.541326530612228, 'year': 75.9795918367347, 'origin': 1.5765306122448979}
```

Comment: what you mean incorrect ? wrong number ? or error code ?

Comment: @W-B my apologies. It produces the wrong number. The min is `100` while the max is `98` which clearly should not be the case as `100>98`

Comment: I have update the question to include output

Comment: dropna will drop whole row when there is one nan in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment above , `dropna` will drop the entire row when there are any `NaN` values in it

```
df = pd.read_csv("Auto.csv")

df["horsepower"].replace("?", np.nan, inplace=True)
df["horsepower"]=pd.to_numeric(df["horsepower"],errors='coerce')
```

Using `describe`

```
df.describe()
```

Comment: This actually excludes the "horsepower" column from the output

Comment: Thank you very much! Why did adding the to_numeric help? Confusing documentation if you ask me.

Comment: @APorter1031 since the you read the data from csv, when there is string in it ,the whole column will upcast to string type , so we need downcast it back to numeric

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having your `horsepower` column's dtype as a float, adding this line works: `df["horsepower"] = df["horsepower"].astype(np.float64)`

Using your example:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Auto.csv")
df["horsepower"].replace("?", np.nan, inplace=True)
df["horsepower"] = df["horsepower"].astype(np.float64)
```

Then for `df.drop(['name'], axis=1).max(axis=0)` I get:

```
mpg               46.6
cylinders          8.0
displacement     455.0
horsepower       230.0
weight          5140.0
acceleration      24.8
year              82.0
origin             3.0
dtype: float64
```

For `df.drop(['name'], axis=1).min(axis=0)` I get:

```
mpg                9.0
cylinders          3.0
displacement      68.0
horsepower        46.0
weight          1613.0
acceleration       8.0
year              70.0
origin             1.0
dtype: float64
```

And for `df.drop(['name'], axis=1).mean(axis=0)` I get:

```
mpg               23.515869
cylinders          5.458438
displacement     193.532746
horsepower       104.469388
weight          2970.261965
acceleration      15.555668
year              75.994962
origin             1.574307
dtype: float64
```